# RecursionError in ed25519.py

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Good morning,

When importing this file in a python script,
http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/python/ed25519.py

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XMR.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ed25519 as ed25519
  File "ed25519.py", line 19, in <module>
    d = -121665 * inv(121666)
  File "ed25519.py", line 17, in inv
    return expmod(x,q-2,q)
  File "ed25519.py", line 12, in expmod
    t = expmod(b,e/2,m)**2 % m
  File "ed25519.py", line 12, in expmod
    t = expmod(b,e/2,m)**2 % m
  File "ed25519.py", line 12, in expmod

    t = expmod(b,e/2,m)**2 % m
  [Previous line repeated 986 more times]
  File "ed25519.py", line 11, in expmod
    if e == 0: return 1
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Do you know what could be going on ?

Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about monero but an EC python library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference ed25519.py implementation uses old Python 2 notation for integer math that has a new meaning in Python 3. I have an updated version as part of MoneroPy that is both Python 2 and 3 compatible at https://github.com/bigreddmachine/MoneroPy. Check in "moneropy>crypto" in the library.

Simply changing the recursion limit *will not* fix the problem. It's not a recursion issue, but an integer division issue.

---

**More details:**

You can see the bulk of the changes that needed to be made here: https://github.com/bigreddmachine/MoneroPy/commit/20e6dbda9224436da7b537a5b062d60cefb7a04d

As you'll see, the primary culprit is that Python 2's definition of "/" is like C/C++, truncating for integer division, while Python 3 has redefined that symbol to mean true division. To prove to yourself that this is the issue, in Python 2.7 you can `from __future__ import divison` and see what happens.

More details on the switch here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189

Comment: I've added more detail above. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This python script should work fine with python2.

If you want to use it with python3, you will have to increase the recursion limit (e.g. `sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)`), and some code fixes might be necessary...

Comment: Thank you sir, indeed it was due to python3. With python2, it is now working.

Comment: This is not correct. It's not a recursion issue, it is a change to how Python 3 does integer math. See my answer for a more complete answer.

Comment: The risen exception was a RecursionError. When I say that is is working, it means that sys.setrecursionlimit(2000) removed the RecursionError (even if other exceptions pumped out).